# Enum over multiple files, or automatic unique constants over multiple files

Tags: c++, enums, constants, c-preprocessor

In C++ is there any way to automatically generate constants over multiple files at compile time? 
Just like how an enum has constants automatically generated in a single file, but the constants must be unique over multiple files.

Eg:

classBase.hpp

```
classBase{
    //blah blah
};
```

classA.hpp

```
class childA : public classBase{
private:
    static const unsigned int mID = NEXT_ID;    
};
```

classB.hpp

```
class childB : public classBase{
private:
    static const unsigned int mID = NEXT_ID;    
};
```

classC.hpp

```
class childC : public classBase{
private:
    static const unsigned int mID = NEXT_ID;    
};
```

So in this case, each class inheriting from classBase would automatically be assigned the next ID (0, 1, 2...)

I would guess there is a way to do it with `#define` s, but I don't know of any way to automatically increment a `#define` each time something is assigned to it, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not easy to generate a sequence at compile time by your own but most compilers supports a macro for this purpose: `__COUNTER__`. It's a counter, increased by the compiler itself each time it's used in source code so you can use it across multiple files. For example your code could be:

```
class childB : public classBase {
private:
    static const unsigned int mID = __COUNTER__;    
};
```

If your compiler doesn't provide that macro (or you need more control over IDs generation) then you have to write much more code but it can be done with [template metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming).

Comment: That sounds good and does work :) I guess the only problem though is if you wanted more than one in a program (I don't in this case), but if in future two or more were needed they would conflict with each other. I don't suppose there's any way of making them separated (__COUNTER__A, __COUNTER__B, etc)?
EDIT: okay, thanks for the template metaprogramming link, I have not come across that before.

Comment: I updated (little bit) the answer. You can do it but you need more code, with t.m. you can generate the sequence in the way you prefer (in theory even using a "seed" based on a parameter or a __FILE__ hash, for example).